# Keyboard dismissing problem - Objective C

Tags: ios, textfield

I have set the delegate of my textfield to self and I have added the delegate for it in the .h, but I have a problem. I want the keyboard to hide If I click **anything but the textfield in the view**. Is this possible? If so, how would I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do some "hacking"... Like this:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

   //glass is a class's property
   if(glass){
      self.glass=nil;
   }
   glass=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)]; //put the size you want.
   [glass addTarget:self action:@selector(hideGlass) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   [self.view insertSubview:glass belowSubview:textField];
}

-(void)hideGlass{
  //remove your glass.
  [glass removeFromSuperview];
  //your textField resigns first responder.
  if([myTextField canResignFirstResponder]){
      [myTextField resignFirstResponder];
  }
}
```

So basically what you do, is to add a dummy button right bellow your textField. So when you touch anything else, excepts your textField, he will make your textField resignFirstResponder and removes himself from the view.

Edit 1 ( the tweek) You just need to replace this:

```
if(glass){
    self.glass=nil;
 }
```

for this:

```
if(glass){
   [glass release];
   glass=nil;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, but what is glass and what do you mean by a class's property?

Comment: Glass is a UIButton. In your .h file add this: UIButton *glass; @property(nonatomic,retain)UIButton *glass; And don't forget in your .m to @synthesize glass.

Comment: Ok looks good. I know UITouch has a property any object, would I be able to make the code easier by using that property?

Comment: The way this code was created, the only way is by using the glass as "@property". If you want, I can tweak a bit so you dont need to "@property" the UIButton *glass.

Comment: I have edited my post... Dont forget in your .h file to add the "UIButton *glass;" statement

Answer (score 1):

I found a simpler way to hide the keyboard and it works when you click on the screen way.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    // endEditing: This method looks at the current view and its subview hierarchy for the text field that is currently the first responder.
    // If it finds one, it asks that text field to resign as first responder
    [[self view] endEditing:TRUE];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to implement the following delegate methods:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I implemented these methods and it still does not hide my keyboard. I am doing:
theTextField.delegate = self; in the VDL and in the .h
UITextFieldDelegate
and in IB I click the textfield, and drag the delegate connection and connect it to the files owner.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an IBOutlet for the `UITextField`, you can dismiss the keyboard using `[textField resignFirstResponder];`.  This being said, you will have to implement event listeners for everything else on the view.  If you want the keyboard to hide when the user taps the view's *background*, it can be done through a touch event in the view controller's implementation:

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

If you have any buttons or subviews, you will have to implement individual touch events or actions for those as well.